# Android: Access the "What's new" Text from Play Store from within my App

Tags: android, google-play

When updating an App in Play Store, one can put a "What's new" or "What has changed" text in all supported languages to the update.
The input field appears when you "upload new APK" in the Developer Console.

Many people miss this text, because there is often more than one update available across all installed Apps on the device, and the user clicks "Update all" in most cases, not looking at the individual update notes.

Now I want to access the text I put in this What's new section from my app-update from within my App, to present it to the user when he starts the App the next time - *in the language of the user*.

Is there any API or dynamic link to play store to gain access to this text? What would be the best approach here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any API that would allow you to pull that information as of today. It is generally a small block of text and you can any day keep a copy of it as a string resource in your app or may be a text file as asset and display as you want to. Alternatively just go for a web page where you keep the history and display the content fetched from the web page inside your app when required.

Comment: Yes that's what we do now - but we wanted to achieve two things: First, stop the double management of text-here-and-text-there and second build a more generic way to use in all apps that doesn't need any extra resources. But thank you for the answer, that there isn't a public API to use. We'll stick to the current way for now.